# LWJGL OpenGL "NoClassDefFoundError" "ClassNotFoundException"

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine

Here's the code:

```
package EngineTester;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;

import renderEngine.DisplayManager;

public class MainGameLoop {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        DisplayManager.createDisplay();

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()) {

            //render
            DisplayManager.updateDisplay();

        }


        DisplayManager.closeDisplay();

    }

}
```

now the error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException
at EngineTester.MainGameLoop.main(MainGameLoop.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.lwjgl.LWJGLException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
```

I don't know what that error means.  By the way line 12 is where it says DisplayManager.updateDisplay();

Comment: I think it means your classpath is not correct. How are you running your application?

Comment: i just click on the run button in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are having trouble with the LWJG-lib you are using.

steps to include the lib:

Moving the library into your project:

1. create a directory in your project-folder, call it lib
2. create a subfolder "natives"
3. create your pack of the LIB via https://www.lwjgl.org/customize [Minimal OpenGl], make sure to choose the right settings for your OS
4. unzip your custom lwjglib.zip
5. move all .jar files without! "javadoc" or "source" in their name in the new created folders
6. move all of those just moved files with "natives" in the subfolder natives

after you moved the files, **refresh your project in eclipse**,

7. Configure Buildpath [rightclick project -> buildpath], choose
8. "Libraries",
   select "Modulepath", use the "add JARS"-button to integrate the files in your lib folder, apply
9. in the same tab, choose "JRE System Library ..." -> Native library location -> select your natives directory, apply and close

edit: you might need some more native files. Check your debug output for any missing .so files, and get them from lwjgl.org, put them in the natives directory. Refresh your project and repeat step 9 after that. (keep the folder as before)